# Updated script from py file while importing to Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Imagine you have created a py file named funcs with a function called my_func().

While using Jupyter Notebook, you want to import said function with the following:

```
from funcs import my_func
```

Now you do something with it, i.e.

```
x = my_func(bla)
```

After that, there is something that you want to modify from my_func. So I change it and save it. If I re-run the code posted above, the change will not be seen, and therefore I am obliged to restart the kernel to run the function with said changes. Is there an efficient way to do it?

**Note:** I know the reload module allows you to reload the entire funcs py file, but I want to do this in a more specific function level. Not the entire script. With reload I would have to import funcs and not just my_func and therefore would have to write

```
x = funcs.my_func(bla)
```

Which isn't my objective.

**Answer:**

```
import sys, importlib
importlib.reload(sys.modules['funcs])
from funcs import my_func
```

Comment: I actually saw that question, the problem there is that you are reloading all the module. I would have to do x = funcs.my_func() and also import funcs and not just the specific python function within the file, which makes it less efficient for my particular type of issues.

Comment: I have edited in order to show this difference. Thank you

Comment: Ok then refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271082/how-to-reload-a-modules-function-in-python).

Comment: You are correct, it is a duplicate. I mark it as duplicate.