# ModuleNotFoundError: spec not found for the module

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am using Jupyter Notebook and trying to use some classes from a `enums.py` file.
If I add new classes to that file, then it seems that I have to always restart the kernel in order to use them in other `.ipynb' files, which is not the best solution.

After searching more, I've found a better solution here [How to reload a module's function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271082/how-to-reload-a-modules-function-in-python), but I'm getting the following error and I'm not sure how to solve that:

> ModuleNotFoundError: spec not found for the module 'enums'

This is my code from `notebook.ipynb`:

```
from importlib import reload
reload(enums)
from enums import FieldTypes, MyEnum
```

And this is the folder structure:

```
  Jupyter_Notebooks
  |--helpers
  |  |-- __init__.py
  |  |-- enums.py
  |  |-- notebook.ipynb
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation (`help(reload)`): "The module must have been successfully imported before."

You must `import enums` for `reload(enums)` to work. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) for details on `from`-imports.

Comment: I have added `import enums` before `from importlib import reload`, but it still throws the same error

Comment: But `import enums` works and `import enums; from importlib import reload; reload(enums)` fails at `reload(enums)`? Does it work in a `.py` file executed via `python` directly?

Comment: Well...I've restarted the kernel and now it's not finding the `enums` module anymore: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'enums'`. I might give up on Jupyter Notebook since you have to do a lot of workarounds in order to get the code organised in modules