# Dynamic reloading of an imported class using class name

Tags: python, dynamic, import

I have a directory with `my_class.py`

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=1

    def message(self):
        print("message =",self.a)
```

I run the following code in a notebook:

```
from my_class import MyClass
MyClass().message() #outputs "message = 1"
```

Suppose now I edit `my_class.py` to replace `self.a=1` with `self.a=2`. I would like to define a function

```
def my_reload(cls):
    # do something
```

such that running

```
my_reload(MyClass)
MyClass().message() #I want this to now output "message = 2"
```

would output 2 instead of 1. How do I do that?

For example, the following code still outputs 1:

```
import importlib
from inspect import getmodule
def my_reload(cls):
    module=getmodule(cls)
    importlib.reload(module)
```

And this

```
from inspect import getmodule
def my_reload(cls):
    module=getmodule(cls)
    __import__(module.__name__+"."+cls.__name__)
```

raises `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_class.MyClass'; 'my_class' is not a package`.

P.S. I would like to keep my import statement `from my_class import MyClass` as is.

**UPD:** This works, but feels slightly evil:

```
import importlib
from inspect import getmodule
def my_reload(cls):
    module=getmodule(cls)
    importlib.reload(module)
    eval("exec('from %s import %s')"%(module.__name__,cls.__name__))
    return eval(cls.__name__)

MyClass=my_reload(MyClass)
MyClass().message() #outputs "message = 2"
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: It's not enough to reload the module; you need to rebind the name `MyClass` because it still refers to the original class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reload a module's function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271082/how-to-reload-a-modules-function-in-python)

Comment: @Woodford @chepner: those answers suggest that after I do `importlib.reload(module)`, I need to do `from my_class import MyClass` again. But how do I do that inside the `my_reload` function? In other words, what's the analog of `from my_class import MyClass` given only the `module` and `cls` variables? I tried `__import__(module.__name__+"."+cls.__name__)` and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: The `from ... import ...` form is not implemented entirely in terms of a call to `import_module` (which should be used in place of a direct call to `__import__`). Once you have a reference to the new module (returned by `import_module`), you can do `MyClass = my_class.MyClass`.